# Matplotlib different precision(scale) on the same axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to setup different stepsize on different intervals of y-axes. For example, step size 1 for values 1-3 and step 0.5 for values 3-5.
Is it possible? So i need something like this (to show all data and keep visibility):
[image]

Comment: Look up function scale in the matplotlib docs

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you give more details please?

Comment: I updated question.